# Updating members details in the DB from CSV files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have small exec(old one) that treat adding members to a table in the DB. if the member not exist in the DB, it will insert new member in AllMember table. If the member already exists in the DB, it will update the values that are different. What exists already in the code is not updating all the members as I want. I want to code it efficiently now. For every update, I am taking all of the members from the DB(6000) and if I have excel with 4000 members it will make the comparison 24000000 and will increase with time.

Getting all the members:

```
 public static IEnumerable<AllMember> GetAllMembersList()
        {
             string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
      using (var dataAccess = new DataAccessDataContext(connection))
            {
                var v = (from row in dataAccess.AllMembers
                        //where row.PremiumType.HasValue && row.PremiumType.Value == 100
                        select row);
                return v.ToList();
            }



            //@TODO fun 

        }
```

Handle the file of new\update members

```
 internal override void ProcessFile()
        {

            StringBuilder CheckMembersList = new StringBuilder();
            CheckMembersList.Clear();
            ErrorFounds = false;
            UpdateQuery = new StringBuilder();

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(InputFile))
            {
                Mail.InsertNewMail("שגיאה בתהליך קליטת פרטי משתמשים ", "הקובץ " + InputFile + " לא נמצא ");
                return;
            }
            CsvReader fileReader = new CsvReader(InputFile, FileEncoding, false, false);
            DataTable fileContentTable = fileReader.ReadFile();
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(InputFile);

            UpdateDB(fileContentTable, CheckMembersList);
            WriteResponseFile(fileContentTable);
}
```

Updating the DB:

```
private void UpdateDB(DataTable inputTable, StringBuilder CheckMembersList)
        {
            IEnumerable<AllMember> allMembersList = Utilities.GetAllMembersList();

            DBUpdateStatus updateStatus = DBUpdateStatus.NO_CHANGE;
            bool x;
            bool newMember;
            int rowIndex=0 ;
            for (int i = 1; i < inputTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                rowIndex = i;
                DataRow fileRow = inputTable.Rows[i];
                newMember = true;
  foreach (AllMember membersRow in allMembersList)
                {

                    if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(membersRow.TZ))) /*&& (fileRow[ConstDBRow.TZ].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(9, '0') == membersRow.TZ.ToString().Trim().PadLeft(9, '0')))*/
                    {
                        newMember = false;
                        updateStatus = UpdateMemberDetails(fileRow, membersRow);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (newMember == true)
                    updateStatus = InsertNewMember(fileRow);



                var memberId = GetMemberId(fileRow[ConstDBRow.TZ].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(9, '0'));
   if (updateStatus != DBUpdateStatus.NO_CHANGE)
                    QueryBuilder.InsertRequest(memberId, updateStatus);

                fileRow["UPDATE_STATUS"] = Utilities.GetStatusString(updateStatus);

                //append to CheckMembersList for sending members list through email
                CheckMembersList.AppendLine("Row Index: " + Convert.ToString(rowIndex + 1) +", Identification number: " + (fileRow[ConstDBRow.TZ].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(9, '0')) + ", First Name: " + fileRow[ConstDBRow.FIRST_NAME].ToString().Replace("'","''") + ", Last Name: " + fileRow[ConstDBRow.LAST_NAME].ToString().Replace("'","''") + ", Update Status: " + fileRow["UPDATE_STATUS"].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "<br/>");
            }

        }
```

How can I do this effectively? Is EntityFramework a good option or taking the list of All-Members differently?

Comment: Import Excel data to a *staging* table in the server DB and run `merge` query.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev can I do it for every file coming in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it on DB to compare the records and insert/update using Merge SQL statement.

There is Merge in SQL Server, hope it is available on other DB servers too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 
As a note: Are you doing insert/update request for each of your record? Try to perform one DB call